# Why do four instances of Chromedriver (w/ Selenium) max out my hard disk usage?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have four different programs with Selenium Webdriver on Python, and when I run them simultaneously, they max out my hard disk usage and make my computer freeze up really often. When I'm using Google Chrome normally, I can have over 25 active tabs open and disk usage won't go over 5%, yet I can't seem to run more than five concurrent Chromedriver instances. The programs aren't even remotely complex, they just reload a page, search for an xpath, wait one second then do it again. I don't get why it does this and have even less of an idea on how to fix it. If anyone can provide any help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Just to make differece, tab is not same as completly new browser. Anyway it is interesting question?

Comment: problem is that each browser will have many processes... for instance, right now I have one instance of Chrome open with one tab.  There are 5 chrome processes running.  If you open another instance of Chrome, you'll have 5 more... etc... and they do tend to gobble up all available cpu time... (even a single instance will spike it pretty good.)  There's also a bit of bloat in the browsers coming from reporting/scanning services.

Comment: if you can get away with it (certain sites/pages may not work with it), HTMLUnit is a much faster and less resource hungry option.  (and headless Chrome is better than non-headless...)

Comment: Is there anything I can do to remove that bloat? Or somehow reduce their disk usage? Almost maxed out disk usage for 4 browsers with only 1 tab open each is outrageous

Comment: you can turn off reporting... and there's probably other options... I'd google, "reducing Chrome resources and disk usage".  (and same for other browsers... Firefox, etc...)